# XFAFlattener constructor seems to do System.exit(0)

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to flatten an XFA Form using XFAFlattener (iText 5.4.5).  My code is almost identical to the FillAndFlatten sample,  Prior to this method being called, the LicenseKey is loaded successfully

```
private void fillAndFlattenForm(File xmlFile, File inputPdf, File outputPdf) throws Exception {
    PdfReader inputPdfReader = null;
    PdfReader outputPdfReader = null;
    PdfStamper stamper = null;
    InputStream inputPdfStream = null;
    InputStream xmlFileStream = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    try {
        // fill the inputPdf using the XML data
        inputPdfStream = new FileInputStream(inputPdf);
        inputPdfReader = new PdfReader(inputPdfStream);
        stamper = new PdfStamper(inputPdfReader, byteOutputStream);
        AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
        XfaForm xfa = form.getXfa();
        xmlFileStream = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
        xfa.fillXfaForm(xmlFileStream);
        stamper.close();
        // the inputPDF has been filled and is in memory in the byteOutputStream; flatten it now
        Document document = new Document();
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputPdf);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fileOutputStream);
        XFAFlattener xfaf = new XFAFlattener(document, writer);
        outputPdfReader = new PdfReader(byteOutputStream.toByteArray());
        xfaf.flatten(outputPdfReader);
        document.close();
    } finally {
        close(stamper);
        IOUtil.close(xmlFileStream);
        close(inputPdfReader);
        IOUtil.close(inputPdfStream);
        close(outputPdfReader);
        IOUtil.close(byteOutputStream);
        IOUtil.close(fileOutputStream);
    }
}
```

What I see happening is that when my code gets to this line

```
XFAFlattener xfaf = new XFAFlattener(document, writer);
```

it just exits.  There is no exception thrown, nor does the code continue after that point.  The error code returned from this process is 0.

I have confirmed that the filling of the form works correctly.

Any ideas on what might be wrong, or what I can do to further diagnose this issue?  Thanks in advance